# Serialize a dictionary in Python with User defined class as a value (Flask)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, serialization

I have a dictionary with Integer keys and a Person class as the value. My GET by user id method is working but my GET UserList method is not.

My GET UserList method is returning:

```
{
    "name": null,
    "age": 0,
    "address": null,
    "city": null,
    "state": null,
    "zip_code": null
}
```

Code snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, fields, marshal_with

user_fields = {
    'name':   fields.String,
    'age':    fields.Integer,
    'address': fields.String,
    'city': fields.String,
    'state': fields.String,
    'zip_code': fields.String
}

class User(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    @marshal_with(user_fields)
    def get(path_user_id):
        # Checks to make sure the user exists otherwise throws an error
        if path_user_id not in user_dict:
            abort(400)

        return user_dict.get(path_user_id)

# This one is not working
class UserList(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    @marshal_with(user_fields)
    def get():
        return user_dict.items()

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, address, city, state, zip_code):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip_code = zip_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You are marshalling you `UserList`'s get method with `user_fields`, just like in `User`, so the reponses are marshalled to have the same format.